# Firebase Cloud Functions - Error: Functions did not deploy properly. - Provided module can't be loaded

Tags: google-cloud-functions

today I had the following after running the command `firebase functions deploy --only functions`.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I found the command `firebase functions:log`

This showed me the "correct" error.

> Provided module can't be loaded. Did you list all required modules in
> the package.json dependencies?

The **solution** to my specific problems was:

remove node_modules folder
`npm install` in functions folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case, After a long time of searching, I found the reason to be that I had disabled billing for the project for some time.

It now worked fine after I enabled it in the `Google cloud console`.

It would have been really helpful if firebase could show any useful error message to suggest the problem. I found this after many trials.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was missing a package in `package.json`